# Mercurial. Colour output piped to less

Tags: command-line, mercurial, less

Operating system: Mac OS 10.6.2

I'd like to be able to see colour output when piping certain commands through less.

Two examples:

I've got ls aliased to `ls --color=auto`, so I'd like to be able to see colour when I do this:

```
ls -l | less
```

I've also got the color extension turned on in Mercurial, so I'd like to see colour output from:

```
hg diff | less
```

and

```
hg st | less
```

After some googling, it seems like some versions of less support either -r or -R to make this work, but no dice for me. I can't see anything in the man page that looks like what I need. (-r or -R SEEM to be the right options, but again, they don't seem to work)

Comment: It looks like the color extension is always disabled when piped. Try these commands to see what I mean: `ls --color=always | ls -R` and `hg diff --config color.mode=ansi | less -R`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For mercurial, you should use the [pager extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PagerExtension) rather than piping explicitly to less. This will play nicely with the colored output options of other hg commands.

Answer (score 13):

I believe you have to use `--color=always` for `ls` if you want it to do colors even when not going to `stdout`. Then use `-r` on the `less` command

```
ls --color=always -l | less -r
```

Answer (score 13):

Do:

```
$ hg diff --color always | less -R
```

I would alias "less -R" to less. I'm not sure if there's a way to provide default options to mercurial's commands so that you don't have to remember to type `--color always` for `hg diff` all the time.

Comment: Or use `$ hg diff --color always | less -FRSXQ` for better less options. It will silently quit if diff fits the screen, for example.

Comment: You can setup LESS="-R" alternatively to aliasing "less" itself.

Comment: `-F` is to keep reading file as it's being produced, `-S` is to not line-wrap, `-X` something obscure, `-Q` avoids ringing terminal bell.

Answer (score 13):

In your ~/.hgrc put:

```
[extensions]
color =
pager =

[pager]
pager = LESS='FRSXQ' less
quiet = True
attend = outgoing,incoming,diff,status,log,qdiff,blame,annotate,pdiff,glog
```

Comment: Why the `quiet = True` part?

Comment: Nice! I recommend `LESS='eiFRSXQ'` to also quit after reaching EOF and ignore case during search

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the [Pager Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PagerExtension) for mercurial you can use the following command:

```
hg diff | cdiff
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Defaults

[defaults]
diff = --color always

Answer (score 0):

`ls --color=auto` means you get colour output when it's *not* being piped to something.  Try `ls --colour=auto | cat` and you'll see what I mean.

I expect hg makes similar assumptions.